# How to map host port range (5000-5004) to the same port (80) in 5 different containers with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run 5 independent instances of the service `website` on host. Each instance will run in a separate container. The containers are created using `docker-compose`. There are specific ports on host pre-allocated for this purpose `(5000-5004)`. The service runs on port `80` in the container. And this should be then mapped to ports `5000`, `5001`, `5002`,`5003`, and`5004` on host.

Then I start the containers with `docker-compose up --scale website=5` which should start 5 instances of the container and map the ports to those specified in the `.yml`.

But this fails with `ERROR: Invalid published port: 5000-5004`.

my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'
services: 
    website:
        image: php:apache
        volumes: ./website:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - "5000-5004:80"
```

Maybe this port mapping is not [valid for docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) but how can I get it working otherwise?

Comment: Documentation suggests that you are legal. How old is your `docker-compose`? `docker-compose --version`

Comment: @spender docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown

Comment: Thanks, installed newest version (1.26.2) and it works! Feel free to post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was fixed in later versions:

https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5428

Are you sure you are using a recent version of `docker-compose`? You can check your current version with:

`docker-compose --version`